# Expected End Sub. Already have End Sub

Tags: vba, excel

I'm posting my entire class. I'm trying to run the `CollectProductsForSalesChannel` Sub called from another method in another module. However, this code won't compile and is telling me that an End Sub is expected. I don't see any blocks of code that haven't been completed and could really use another set of constructive eyes.

I'm getting a compile error in the `CollectProductsForSalesChannel` sub just before the actual `End Sub`.

Here is my `Customer` Class which works with another `Product` class

```
Private cProducts As Dictionary
Private cName As String
Private myEndRow As Long
Private myStartRow As Long
Private sumVolume As Double
Private sumRev As Double
Private avgPrice As Double
Private sumVolVar As Double

Public Property Get SumPoundsSold() As Double
    SumPoundsSold = sumVolume
End Property

Public Property Let SumPoundsSold(val As Double)
    sumVolume = val
End Property

Public Property Get SumRevenue() As Double
    SumRevenue = sumRev
End Property

Public Property Let SumRevenue(val As Double)
    sumRev = val
End Property

Public Property Get AveragePrice() As Double
    AveragePrice = avgPrice
End Property

Public Property Let AveragePrice(val As Double)
    avgPrice = val
End Property

Public Property Get VolumeVariance() As Double
    VolumeVariance = sumVolVar
End Property

Public Property Let VolumeVariance(val As Double)
    sumVolVar = val
End Property

Public Property Set Products(col As Dictionary)
    Set cProducts = col
End Property

Public Property Get Products() As Dictionary
    Set Products = cProducts
End Property

Public Property Let Name(val As String)
    cName = val
End Property

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = cName
End Property

Public Property Let StartRow(val As Long)
    myStartRow = val
End Property

Public Property Get StartRow() As Long
    StartRow = myStartRow
End Property

Public Property Let EndRow(val As Long)
    myEndRow = val
End Property

Public Property Get EndRow() As Long
    EndRow = myEndRow
End Property

Public Sub InitMe()
    Set cProducts = New Dictionary
End Sub

Public Sub CollectProductsForSalesChannel(tbl As ListObject)

    Dim productNumber As String 'Product search reference
    Dim lRow As ListRow 'ListRow iteration
    Dim adjProd As Product 'Existing product to append to
    Dim newProduct As Product 'New Product

    With tbl

        For Each lRow In .ListRows

            If .ListColumns("Customer").DataBodyRange(lRow.Index).Value = cName Then

                productNumber = .ListColumns("Number").DataBodyRange(lRow.Index).Value & .ListColumns("Alt Number").DataBodyRange(lRow.Index).Value

                Set newProduct = New Product
                newProduct.PrimalNumber = .ListColumns("Number").DataBodyRange(lRow.Index).Value
                newProduct.SecondsNumber = .ListColumns("Alt Number").DataBodyRange(lRow.Index).Value
                newProduct.Name = .ListColumns("Product").DataBodyRange(lRow.Index).Value
                newProduct.PoundsSold = .ListColumns("Pounds Sold").DataBodyRange(lRow.Index).Value
                newProduct.SalesDollars = .ListColumns("Sales Dollars").DataBodyRange(lRow.Index).Value
                newProduct.TargetProfit = .ListColumns("Target Profit").DataBodyRange(lRow.Index).Value
                newProduct.VolumeVariance = .ListColumns("Volume Variance").DataBodyRange(lRow.Index).Value
                newProduct.PriceVariance = 0

                If Not cProducts.Exists(productNumber) Then

                    Me.AddProduct1 newProduct

                Else

                    Set adjProd = cProducts(productNumber)
                    adjProd.PoundsSold = adjProd.PoundsSold + newProduct.PoundsSold
                    adjProd.SalesDollars = adjProd.SalesDollars + newProduct.SalesDollars
                    adjProd.TargetProfit = adjProd.TargetProfit + newProduct.TargetProfit
                    adjProd.VolumeVariance = adjProd.VolumeVariance + newProduct.VolumeVariance

                End If

                Me.SumPoundsSold = Me.SumPoundsSold + newProduct.PoundsSold
                Me.SumRevenue = Me.SumRevenue + newProduct.SalesDollars
                Me.AveragePrice = 0
                Me.VolumeVariance = Me.VolumeVariance + newProduct.VolumeVariance

            End If

        Next lRow

    End With

End Sub

Public Sub AddProduct1(prod As Product)

    Dim productNumber As String: productNumber = prod.PrimalNumber & prod.SecondsNumber
    cProducts.Add productNumber, prod

End Sub
```

Below is the `Segment Class`, which calls the `CollectProductsForSalesChannel` Sub.

```
Private sCustomers As Dictionary
Private sName As String
Private IsKA As Boolean
Private CustChecks As Collection

Public Sub InitMe()
    Set sCustomers = New Dictionary
    Set CustChecks = New Collection
End Sub

Public Property Set Customers(col As Dictionary)
    Set sCustomers = col
End Property

Public Property Get Customers() As Dictionary
    Set Customers = sCustomers
End Property

Public Property Let Name(val As String)
    sName = val
End Property

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = sName
End Property

Public Property Let IsKeyAccounts(val As Boolean)
    IsKA = val
End Property

Public Property Get IsKeyAccounts() As Boolean
    IsKeyAccounts = IsKA
End Property

Public Sub AddCustomerCheck(custStr As String)
    CustChecks.Add custStr
End Sub

'This collects all Customers by Sales Channel as opposed to Segment name
Public Sub AddCustomersAndProductsBySalesChannel(tbl As ListObject)

    Dim newCustomer As Customer
    Dim lRow As ListRow

    With tbl

        For Each lRow In .ListRows

            If .ListColumns("Sales Channel").DataBodyRange(lRow.Index).Value = sName Then

                If Not sCustomers.Exists(.ListColumns("Customer").DataBodyRange(lRow.Index).Value) Then

                    Set newCustomer = New Customer
                    newCustomer.InitMe
                    newCustomer.Name = .ListColumns("Customer").DataBodyRange(lRow.Index).Value
                    sCustomers.Add newCustomer.Name, newCustomer
                    newCustomer.CollectProductsForSalesChannel tbl

                End If

            End If

        Next lRow

    End With

End Sub
```

`Product` Class:

```
Private pName As String
Private pNumber As String
Private sNumber As String
Private prodName As String
Private pLine As Integer
Private pMcDFactor As Double
Private pProductionPounds As Double
Private pPoundsSold As Double
Private pSalesDollars As Double
Private pEBITDAProfit As Double
Private pTargetProfit As Double
Private pMcDResChange As Double
Private pPriceVar As Double
Private pVolVar As Double

Public Property Let PriceVariance(val As Double)
    pPriceVar = val
End Property

Public Property Get PriceVaraince() As Double
    PriceVariance = pPriceVar
End Property

Public Property Let VolumeVariance(myVariance As Double)
    pVolVar = myVariance
End Property

Public Property Get VolumeVariance() As Double
    VolumeVariance = pVolVar
End Property

Public Property Let Name(val As String)
    prodName = val
End Property

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = prodName
End Property

Public Property Let PrimalNumber(val As String)
    pNumber = val
End Property

Public Property Get PrimalNumber() As String
    PrimalNumber = pNumber
End Property

Public Property Let SecondsNumber(val As String)
    sNumber = val
End Property

Public Property Get SecondsNumber() As String
    SecondsNumber = sNumber
End Property

Public Property Let PlantName(val As String)
    pName = val
End Property

Public Property Get PlantName() As String
    pName = pName
End Property

Public Property Let ProductLine(val As Integer)
    pLine = val
End Property

Public Property Get ProductLine() As Integer
    ProductLine = pLine
End Property

Public Property Let McDonaldsFactor(val As Double)
    pMcDFactor = val
End Property

Public Property Get McDonaldsFactor() As Double
    McDonaldsFactor = pMcDFactor
End Property

Public Property Let PoundsSold(val As Double)
    pPoundsSold = val
End Property

Public Property Get PoundsSold() As Double
    PoundsSold = pPoundsSold
End Property

Public Property Let SalesDollars(val As Double)
    pSalesDollars = val
End Property

Public Property Get SalesDollars() As Double
    SalesDollars = pSalesDollars
End Property

Public Property Let EBITDAProfit(val As Double)
    pEBITDAProfit = val
End Property

Public Property Get EBITDAProfit() As Double
    EBITDAProfit = pEBITDAProfit
End Property

Public Property Let TargetProfit(val As Double)
    pTargetProfit = val
End Property

Public Property Get TargetProfit() As Double
    TargetProfit = pTargetProfit
End Property

Public Property Let ProductionPounds(val As Double)
    pProductionPounds = val
End Property

Public Property Get ProductionPounds() As Double
    ProductionPounds = pProductionPounds
End Property

Public Property Let McDResChange(val As Double)
    pMcDResChange = val
End Property

Public Property Get McDResChange() As Double
    McDResChange = pMcDResChange
End Property
```

The only thing I can really think of would be maybe I missed something in my Get/Let methods but I'm obviously missing something.

Comment: That code compiles OK for me.

Comment: I've  pasted it into Notepad++ and reviewed it a few times but it looks fine. I don't know why Excel won't compile it for me.

Comment: Not compiling for me - `Product` in declarations is giving `User-defined type not defined`, `cname` isn't defined.

Comment: It's part of a larger Class Module

Comment: FYI: There is a typo in the line (Value): adjProd.PoundsSold = adjProd.PoundsSold + .ListColumns("Pounds Sold").DataBodyRange(lRow.Index).vlaue

Comment: Word of advice: code patterns like this will be terribly difficult to debug (as you are now seeing). I would strongly recommend creating a product class that stores the values from your table, and dont bother the parent with the details of the child (`AddProduct arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, etc.` would become `AddProduct Product`. Likewise, clean up indentation and spacing, that makes code easier to read as well.

Comment: I have a product class. adjProduct is an instance of that class. This class is Customer

Comment: Additionally, an array would be far better suited for the task you're trying to accomplish. If you can properly index the array your code will be much easier to read, but it will also be a lot cleaner.

Comment: @jDave1984 Then you need some kind of sub-class that holds the properties you are passing in as arguments. Having a paragraph of arguments is a very strong code smell.

Comment: This line has an error: `adjProd.PoundsSold = adjProd.PoundsSold + .ListColumns("Pounds Sold").DataBodyRange(lRow.Index).vlaue`. "vlaue". Try fix that

Comment: Also I don't want to get defensive, but the code indentation is just fine and adheres to best practices. The reason I have the AddProduct method is based on preference. I would have to assign the properties the same way and would have needed a few more extra lines

Comment: @RafaelMatos that's been fixed, and isn't the issue

Comment: @BrandonBarney this class uses a Dictionary, which is needed. Thanks for the help, though

Comment: @jDave1984 Indentation and spacing certainly doesnt adhere to best practices. Yes, you have indented by hierarchy, but there is literally no additional whitespace encouraging readability. The line continuation tokens confuse the code as well, and then the one line `If` block. Not being a jerk here, but there's a reason why these kinds of, otherwise easy to fix, bugs can hide so well.

Comment: OK, then. I can't see the error, but I would try comment all the If statements, and uncomment it little by little, to see where the error is.

Comment: The line tokens are a necessity in this case. Please don't turn this thread into an argument about best practices.

Comment: @jDave1984 I am not turning it into an argument about best practices. It is literally the reason why all of us are having a hard time finding the bug (or why the bug doesnt actually exist, but it is impossible to guarantee).

Comment: The code has compiled for @TimWilliams

Comment: In line 28 there is missing a `.Value`, but I think that is not the issue you are looking for

Comment: Nope. Already fixed, but not the issue. Thanks though

Comment: You need to read about how to make a proper [MCVE]. This code requires a ton of work on our part just to get it to compile... and then when we do, it compiles just fine - i.e. the code you're showing us is entirely irrevant to the problem you say you're having.

Comment: Maybe on line 34 there is a `(lRow.Index).Value` missing? Or is that ok?

Comment: @TimWilliams me too (after adding `Sub AddProduct(ParamArray foo())` and 4 `Property Get`+`Property Let` members). Hence my voting to close for lack of a [mcve].

Comment: Considering @BrandonBarney and Mat were having trouble reading my code, I've cleaned it up

Comment: @Mat'sMug the entire question has been reworded. Please, if you can, open this again. I am wracking my brain about it

Comment: That's great, but it still doesn't reproduce the problem - code compiles fine... given a `Product` class with `Name`, `PoundsSold`, `PriceVariance`, `PrimalNumber`, `SalesDollars`, `SecondsNumber`, `TargetProfit` and `VolumeVariance` public fields (or properties). Did you try copying that code into a brand new VBA project and see for yourself that there is no compile error? Did you modify the code in any way before posting? Skipped parts maybe? I had to add an `AddProduct` method to the `Customer` class for it to compile.

Comment: This is really strange. I've literally taken the `ColectProductsForSalesChannel` sub and moved it to the top of the class, just above all of my property methods, and now the expected End Sub error hits in the `InitMe` method.

Comment: And I did leave out the `AddProduct` method. My bad. I'll add that and the Product Class

Comment: In any case I think you're going to end up figuring it out on your own, much faster than you can make this post replicate your error. I'd just delete the question.

Comment: I've just posted the Product class. I've never ran into this error before, though. I assumed I was missing something obvious like forgot to close a code block, but I'm not seeing it

Comment: It's entirely possible the project is corrupted. VBA doesn't care much about the source code you can see and edit in the VBE; the VBE itself isn't displaying the source code you enter - when you hit [ENTER] it processes that instruction and renders the VBA code for the underlying P-Code. Sometimes a disconnect happens between the underlying P-Code and the VBA source code in the editor. Might be what's happening here.

Comment: One of the reasons I absolutely hate the VBE. Although I think I might have isolated the problem into the Segment class (maybe). I exported all three classes into a new workbook and just tried to do a test. Intellisense stops working around the `AddCustomersAndProductsBySalesChannel` Method

Comment: Your `PlantName` get property is not assigning a result, only reassigning your field.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in comments, part of the problem you are having is with the readability of your code. It doesnt take much to clean up dirty code (and it doesnt take much to make clean code dirty).

Note, I havent changed what your code *does* just a little bit of *how* it does it. In the process, notice how I need fewer variables, less if blocks, and the code is much easier to read. Not to mention it doesnt push the right side of the screen.

```
Public Sub NewCollectProductsForSalesChannel(ByVal Table As ListObject)
    Dim InputData As Variant
    InputData = Table.Range.Value

    Dim HeaderIndices As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set HeaderIndices = GetHeaderIndices(InputData)

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(InputData, 1) + 1 To UBound(InputData, 1)
        ' Assuming cName is a private Class Variable?
        ' Cut FoundCustomer since it doesnt do anything beyond create a non-needed If block.
        If InputData(i, HeaderIndices("Customer")) = cName Then
            Dim ProductID As String
            ProductID = InputData(i, HeaderIndices("Number")) & InputData(i, HeaderIndices("Alt Number"))
            If Not cProducts.Exists(ProductID) Then
                ' Less than ideal, but in lieue of a proper defined type...
                AddProduct _
                    InputData(i, HeaderIndices("Plant Name")), _
                    InputData(i, HeaderIndices("Number")), _
                    InputData(i, HeaderIndices("Alt Number")), _
                    InputData(i, HeaderIndices("Product")), _
                    InputData(i, HeaderIndices("Product Line")), _
                    InputData(i, HeaderIndices("McD Factor")), _
                    InputData(i, HeaderIndices("Pounds Sold")), _
                    InputData(i, HeaderIndices("Sales Dollars")), _
                    0, _
                    InputData(i, HeaderIndices("Target Profit")), _
                    0, _
                    0, _
                    0, _
                    InputData(i, HeaderIndices("Volume Variance"))
            Else
                With cProducts(ProductID)
                    .PoundsSold = InputData(i, HeaderIndices("Pounds Sold"))
                    .SalesDollars = InputData(i, HeaderIndices("Sales Dollars"))
                    .TargetProfit = InputData(i, HeaderIndices("Target Profit"))
                    .VolumeVariance = InputData(i, HeaderIndices("Volume Variance"))
                End With

                sumvol = sumvol + InputData(i, HeaderIndices("Pounds Sold"))
                sumRev = sumRev + InputData(i, HeaderIndices("Sales Dollars"))
                avgPrice = 0
                sumVolVar = sumVolVar + InputData(i, HeaderIndices("Volume Variance"))
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Public Function GetHeaderIndices(ByVal InputData As Variant) As Scripting.Dictionary
    If IsEmpty(InputData) Then Exit Function

    Dim HeaderIndices As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set HeaderIndices = New Scripting.Dictionary

    HeaderIndices.CompareMode = TextCompare

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(InputData, 2) To UBound(InputData, 2)
        If Not HeaderIndices.Exists(Trim(InputData(LBound(InputData, 1), i))) Then _
           HeaderIndices.Add Trim(InputData(LBound(InputData, 1), i)), i
    Next

    Set GetHeaderIndices = HeaderIndices
End Function
```

This didn't take long to write, and frankly I would have cleaned it up more if it was my code (this is begging for a sub class or two).

Also, I would recommend browsing CodeReview for ideas on how to improve your classes. A well-known user, Mat's Mug, uses a `this` for his private variables and it is a game changer for classes.

Best of luck. You may not like my advice, but you'll have a hard time arguing that your code is cleaner than mine.

Comment: This answer does not help whatsoever. Thanks for trying, though

Comment: I understand he did and I appreciate the help. Except the code structure is not the issue. Thanks again for your attempts

Comment: @jDave1984 FWIW - I figured out where you problem likely lies, and if you took the time to not get defensive about your code, and instead tried to use the feedback to improve you would quickly find and solve the problem as well. The thing is, bad code makes it really easy to hide mistakes, such as removing the problem that caused the issue before posting to SO. Taking a wild guess here, but those 0's are actually properties you removed for confidentiality purposes? Another wild guess here, but you missed your missing `"` or `( / )` because of all of the in-necessary bits?

Comment: Before assuming we are wrong, assume you are wrong. I know that sounds cocky, but if I balked every time someone tried to help me improve my code, I would be a really crappy programmer who would spend more time fixing bad code than I would writing new code, and learning new things. I'm not going to waste more time here, because there are plenty of SO users willing to accept the help we offer, but you will find yourself wasting a lot of time fixing bad code if you don't take the time to recognize bad code in the first place.

Comment: 1.) I've always assumed I was wrong (which is why I post questions on SO). However, the formatting of the code, I knew wasn't the issue. I thank you for looking at it and attempting to help, what I don't appreciate is the personal attack. 
And the 0's are hard-coded for now after I finish the initial test of the code.

Having said that, though, I did put those zeros a little hastily working behind a deadline. If you want to post that as the answer you'll get best answer, despite our initial rapport.

Comment: Actually on further revision: that is not the issue.

Comment: Cleaner code has been posted if you want to take another look at it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153387/discussion-between-jdave1984-and-brandon-barney).